# Assigning multiple styles for same layer from GeoServer in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

This is my code, the function set style is not working osm background layer. I have many sld files for one layer and I want apply them on the same

```
layer:
<script>
var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ratio: 1,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/westernghats/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format,
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'westernghats:UKNEWPANESR2015',
          }
        })
      });
      var tiled = new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/westernghats/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format, 
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                   tiled: true,
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'westernghats:UKNEWPANESR2015',
          }
        })
      });
      //Openstreetmap layer
      var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
      }); 
    osm.set('name', 'OSM');
var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attribution: false
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        target: 'map',
        layers: [ osm,
          untiled,
          tiled  
        ]
 });

//Function to call styles
function setStyle(style){
        map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
          lyr.getSource().updateParams({'STYLES': style});
        });
      }
<script>
<body>
<div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
      <ul><li>
          <a>Styles:</a>
          <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setStyle(value)">
            <option value="">Default</option>
               <option value="BIOMASSGG-WEI">BIOMASSGG-WEI</option>  
               <option value="AGRO-WEIGHT">AGRO-WEIGHT</option>  
               <option value="BIOMASSGG">BIOMASSGG</option>  
               <option value="BIOENERGYSD">BIOENERGYSD</option>  
               <option value="BIOENERGYSD-WEIsld">BIOENERGYSD-WEIsld</option>  
               <option value="AGROCLIMATICZONE">AGROCLIMATICZONE</option>  
          </select>
        </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi - did you have any luck?

Comment: hello -  your help appreciated